# how to change stroke color on svg in <img> tag?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an svg file, say a.svg, with the content:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <line x1="25" y1="15" x2="35" y2="24.6" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round"/>
        <line x1="25" y1="35" x2="35" y2="24.6" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

The svg has no stroke color, but I want to be able to set the stroke color in css when I import this svg with an  tag like so:

HTML:

```
<img src="a.svg">
```

CSS:

```
img {
    stroke: red;
    /* This doesn't work */
}
```

How am I able to do this?

Comment: You can try using border for image . Since you are using svg as an src import for image .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the SVG is in an `<img>` tag, you can't style it with CSS. Consider using something like inline SVG. See https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#article-header-id-6 for more details.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to style an svg imported via the  tag. You have to edit your svg file and the changes will automatically appear on your html page.
Basing on your svg, the new code has to look like:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 50">
    <g fill-rule="evenodd">
        <line x1="25" y1="15" x2="35" y2="24.6" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round"/>
        <line x1="25" y1="35" x2="35" y2="24.6" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Just add stroke="blue" on both `line` tags (replace blue with the color of your choice)