# Changing the fill color of SVG with Tailwind CSS not working

Tags: html, css, svg, tailwind-css, fill

I want the color of my SVG icon to be white by default and to become red on hover.
But in my current code it is always white and does not change on hover. Why?

Here is my code:

index.html file:

```
<img src="images/social/icon-facebook.svg" alt="facebook logo"
    class="w-7 h-7 hover:fill-red-400">
```

icon-facebook.svg file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20">
    <path fill="#FFF" d="M18.896 0H1.104C.494 0 0 .494 0 1.104v17.793C0 19.506.494 20 1.104 20h9.58v-7.745H8.076V9.237h2.606V7.01c0-2.583 1.578-3.99 3.883-3.99 1.104 0 2.052.082 2.329.119v2.7h-1.598c-1.254 0-1.496.597-1.496 1.47v1.928h2.989l-.39 3.018h-2.6V20h5.098c.608 0 1.102-.494 1.102-1.104V1.104C20 .494 19.506 0 18.896 0z"/>
</svg>
```

---

I also noticed, that defining the white default color with a Tailwind CSS class on the `img` tag instead of using the `fill` attribute in the SVG file doesn't work either - the icon will just be black.
**Why do my Tailwind CSS classes not have any effect at all here?**

index.html file:

```
<img src="images/social/icon-facebook.svg" alt="facebook logo"
    class="w-7 h-7 fill-white hover:fill-red-400">
```

icon-facebook.svg file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="20">
    <path d="M18.896 0H1.104C.494 0 0 .494 0 1.104v17.793C0 19.506.494 20 1.104 20h9.58v-7.745H8.076V9.237h2.606V7.01c0-2.583 1.578-3.99 3.883-3.99 1.104 0 2.052.082 2.329.119v2.7h-1.598c-1.254 0-1.496.597-1.496 1.47v1.928h2.989l-.39 3.018h-2.6V20h5.098c.608 0 1.102-.494 1.102-1.104V1.104C20 .494 19.506 0 18.896 0z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You can not affect anything inside an SVG that you embed via `img`, from the outside via CSS. You would need to put the actual `<svg>...</svg>` directly into your HTML. https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#aa-the-problem-with-both-img-and-background-image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24933430/20594090) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11978995/20594090) question.
Could be marked as duplicate like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55744607/20594090) or  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40343354/20594090) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59211112/20594090)  with references to both two largely viewed questions like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56277291/20594090) has. The new that it brings to the table is Tailwind CSS.

Answer (score 3):

The **issue** you're facing **is not Tailwind-specific**. If you would write normal CSS, like the following...

```css
img:hover {
    fill: #f87171; 
}
```

...it would not work either.

The problem here lies in the fact (as [@CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) already commented), that **you cannot style an SVG that you embed via the `img` tag with CSS** (as you can read in [this](https://yourillust.com/how-to-change-svg-colors-with-css/#when-displaying-svg-with-img-tags) or [this](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/#aa-the-problem-with-both-img-and-background-image) article).

#### Solutions

I layed out several approaches **[in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76964757/20594090) in detail**. In short:

- don't embed SVGs with the `img` tag, but instead use the `svg` tag (*recommended*)
- or use a script to transform those `img` tags into `svg` tags (*not recommended*)
- or use some other workaround, like `masks`, `filters`, or the `background-image` property

#### Easiest solution (recommended)

Embed SVGs with the `svg` element in the HTML.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="bg-gray-900">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" alt="facebook logo" class="w-7 h-7 fill-white hover:fill-red-400">
            <path
                d="M18.896 0H1.104C.494 0 0 .494 0 1.104v17.793C0 19.506.494 20 1.104 20h9.58v-7.745H8.076V9.237h2.606V7.01c0-2.583 1.578-3.99 3.883-3.99 1.104 0 2.052.082 2.329.119v2.7h-1.598c-1.254 0-1.496.597-1.496 1.47v1.928h2.989l-.39 3.018h-2.6V20h5.098c.608 0 1.102-.494 1.102-1.104V1.104C20 .494 19.506 0 18.896 0z" />
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

> **Tailwind itself does it like that whenever possible**, as you can see on their [homepage](https://tailwindcss.com/) or [the Tailwind UI page](https://tailwindui.com/) (I didn't find a single `img` embed). You can check this by right clicking on every icon there and picking "Inspect". Or short `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `C`.
> **However, when they need to embed it from a remote source and do not care about further changing the styling via CSS** (`https://...`), they do and must use the `img` tag, because [there is no `src` attribute supported on the `svg` tag](https://css-tricks.com/svg-loader-a-different-way-to-work-with-external-svg/). They do this for example in [Tailwind Components](https://tailwindui.com/components/), like [this Landing Page Template](https://tailwindui.com/components/marketing/page-examples/landing-pages) here.
> But in serious full-blown [Tailwind Templates](https://tailwindui.com/templates) like [this one](https://tailwindui.com/templates/salient), where they have a custom company logo, they always stick to embedding it as `svg` element.

#### Improvements to your SVG

- you need to define the viewBox attribute on the SVG file to make it scalable - without it, you can't increase or decrease its size. That's why **I added `viewBox="0 0 20 20"`.**
- the `width="20"` and `height="20"` in your SVG file are unnecessary, since the dimensions are already defined by the path itself and the viewBox - setting the `width` and `height` there only prevents you from scaling it. That's why **I removed them.**

`index.html` file:

```html
<img src="icon-facebook.svg" alt="facebook logo"
    class="w-7 h-7 fill-white hover:fill-red-400">
```

`icon-facebook.svg` file:

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <path d="M18.896 0H1.104C.494 0 0 .494 0 1.104v17.793C0 19.506.494 20 1.104 20h9.58v-7.745H8.076V9.237h2.606V7.01c0-2.583 1.578-3.99 3.883-3.99 1.104 0 2.052.082 2.329.119v2.7h-1.598c-1.254 0-1.496.597-1.496 1.47v1.928h2.989l-.39 3.018h-2.6V20h5.098c.608 0 1.102-.494 1.102-1.104V1.104C20 .494 19.506 0 18.896 0z"/>
</svg>
```